# Jacobi identity and Leibniz rule - the same thing?

Tags: soft-question, lie-groups, lie-algebras, differential

Is there any formal connection between the Jacobi identity
$$[[a,b],c] = [a,[b,c]] + [b,[c,a]]$$
and the Leibniz rule
$$d(a \cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot d(b) \cdot c + b \cdot c \cdot d(a) ~\text{?}$$

Comment: That's a bit odd compatibility formula between $d$ and $\cdot$ (which I presume is associative)...how did you get it? If I multiply the Jacobi rule $d(ab)=(da) b\pm a (db)$ on the right by $c$ I get $d(ab)c=(da) b c\pm a (db) c$:

Comment: If you think if Lie bracket of vector fields, then the bracket is the antisymmetrized differentiation. Hence, Jacobi follows from Leibnitz in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, with $d=\operatorname{ad}(x)(y)$, the adjoint operator in a Lie algebra, defined by $\operatorname{ad}(x)(y)=[x,y]$.
Then the Jacobi identity is equivalent to the statement that the operator $d$ satisfies the Leibniz rule, with $x.y=[x,y]$:
$$
    d([a,b])=[d(a),b]+[a,d(b)]
$$
Applying $\operatorname{ad}(c)$ yields $[d([a,b]),c]=[[d(a),b],c]+[[a,d(b)],c]$.

Comment: If it was meant that $(L,[,],\cdot)$ is a Poisson algebra, then $d(a\cdot b)=d(a)\cdot b+a\cdot d(b)$, and $d(a\cdot b)\cdot c=d(a)\cdot b\cdot c+a\cdot d(b)\cdot c$.